# How to remove repeating white-space characters from UTF8 string in PHP properly with regex?

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, whitespace

I'm trying to remove repeating white-space characters from UTF8 string in PHP using regex.
This regex

```
    $txt = preg_replace( '/\s+/i' , ' ', $txt );
```

usually works fine, but some of the strings have Cyrillic letter "Р", which is screwed after the replacement.
After small research I realized that the letter is encoded as  \x{D0A0}, and since \xA0 is non-breaking white space in ASCII the regex replaces it with \x20 and the character is no longer valid.

Any ideas how to do this properly in PHP with regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is described @ http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#106981

If you want to catch characters, as well european, russian, chinese, japanese, korean of whatever, just:

- use mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
- use preg_replace('`...`u', '...', $string) with the u (unicode) modifier

For further information, the complete list of preg_* modifiers could be found at :
http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Thank you both **asciimoo** and **Passerby**. I definitely missed this in the manual

Answer (score 5):

Try the `u` modifier:

```
$txt="UTF 字符串 with 空格符號";
var_dump(preg_replace("/\\s+/iu","",$txt));
```

Outputs:

```
string(28) "UTF字符串with空格符號"
```

Comment: This saved my day, couldn't get `&#xa0;` removed.